# How to change content background colour for Jquery Accordion

Tags: jquery

How to change content background colour for Jquery Accordion? I've tried to change it in CSS and JS file:

[CSS]

```
.ui-accordion-content {  
    width: 100%;  
    background-color: #f3f3f3;  
    color: #777;  
    font-size: 10pt;  
    line-height: 16pt;  
}
```

[JS]

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("background", "#fcfff4")
```

none of them works.

Comment: You have to use a more specific CSS selector. Read the standard on what takes precedence for browsers choosing which CSS selectors for an element. So something like #myAccordion .ui-accordion-content might do it. Or you might have to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer: You need to be aware of CSS selector precedence.

You have to use a more specific CSS selector. Read the standard on what takes precedence for browsers choosing which CSS selectors for an element. So something like

```
#myAccordion .ui-accordion-content
```

might do it. Or you might have to be more specific.

Here are a few links to more information about this:

- [Precedence in CSS selector specifity conflicts (type vs class selector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666581/precedence-in-css-conflicts)
- http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence

Answer (score 2):

override  `.ui-widget-content`

```
.ui-widget-content{
    background:red;
}
```

Look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/aPVZR/) , I forked an accordion and just changed the background

Answer (score 2):

I try and use more specific selectors and always add the background:none;

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-header{
  background-image:none;
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
}

#accordion .ui-accordion-content{
  font-size:14px;
  background-image:none;
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the world `!important` in your **CSS** because you are overriding the default CSS settings of **JQuery-UI**, or maybe you should **set/customize** the **Theme** of your desired JQuery-UI theme before downloading the JQuery-UI

Comment: Can you use !important when setting it through jQuery.css()?

Comment: @Precastic see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles

Comment: @Þaw Yes, but that is not function of jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<style>
#accordion .ui-state-active{
background-image:none;
background-color:#FF0000!important;
color:#454545!important;
border: 1px solid #454545!important;
}

#accordion .ui-state-default{
background-image:none;
background-color:#F6F6F6;
color:#454545;
}
</style>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to the party, but I would go like this:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: WRITE HERE WHATEVER COLOUR YOU WISH ;
}
```