# My <a hrefs does not send me to elements within my document

Tags: html, css, anchor, href

Ok, so I am making a one-pager with 4 different 'pages'.
Everything was working normally before, I was referring to elements on the page that had an ID in CSS, and it worked like a charm.

However, now it does not. It does move me somehow, but never correct, and the weirdest thing is that it varies for each time!

This is how my menu look like.

```
<a href="#one" class="smoothScroll"> Kom i gang </a></li>
<a href="#two" class="smoothScroll"> Utstyr</a> </li>
<a href="#three" class="smoothScroll"> Oppskrifter</a> </li>
<a href="#four" class="smoothScroll"> Kontakt </a></li>
```

This is how one of the elements I am linking to look like in CSS:

```
#two {
    position: absolute;
    height: 120%;
    top: 275%;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 4px #444444 outset;
    border-bottom: 4px #444444 outset;
    background-color: #C7A066;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('../img/pattern.png');
}
```

I hope somebody can help me :-) 
It's quite annoying!

tl;dr the links does not seem to take me to the element i'm referring to. what has gone wrong?

Comment: And where are the elements that have an `id` of `one` or `two`...?

Comment: They are sections within the body element, like this:
<body>
<section id="one"> </section>
</body>

Comment: This works fine for me? http://jsfiddle.net/p3a701nq/ Can you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Your `<li>` starting tags are missing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ID Selector in CSS or class selector. If you go with both then selector preferences matters.

**1. ID Selector:**

```
<a href="#one" id="one"> Kom i gang </a></li>
```

CSS:

```
   #one {
    position: absolute;
    height: 120%;
    top: 275%;
    z-index: 1000;
   }
```

**2. Class Selector:**

```
<a href="#one" class="smoothScroll"> Kom i gang </a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.smoothScroll { 
  position: absolute;
  height: 120%;
  top: 275%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

[CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) and
for selector [precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666581/precedence-in-css-selector-specifity-conflicts-type-vs-class-selector)

Comment: What does "selector preferences" mean? Why would this have anything to do with the behavior of clicking on a link and jumping somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, smoothScroll is javascript that makes it scroll smoothly. I'm only using ID Selector.